# Restoring last opened pdf page after back key press

Tags: java, android, restore, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

After back key pressed, I have implemented this code to restore my last opened page in PDF document. Unfortunately, it still load the first page.

```
    pdfView1 = findViewById(R.id.pdfViewer1);
    pdfView1.fromAsset("cpgTest1.pdf")
            .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
            .defaultPage(currentPage)
            .onPageChange(this)
            .load();
}

@Override
public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount)
{
    currentPage = page;
}

@Override
public void loadComplete(int nbPages)
{
    if (currentPage >= 0)
    {
        pdfView1.jumpTo(currentPage);
    }}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(KEY_CURRENT_PAGE, currentPage);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    currentPage = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_CURRENT_PAGE);
}

}
```

Any thought?

Comment: Please edit the question and at least tag the language you’re using as well as the platform so people can help you

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have edited it. Hopefully it is understandable now

Comment: Android Studio is an IDE, the platform is Android. Android Studio tag should only be used with issues with the IDE, which is not the case here so tag Android. Also do tag the language used.